# Remove image from My Site Profile settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, my-profile

I've setup a sharepoint site that initially had My Sites turned on.  One of our users went in and uploaded a picture for their profile.  Then we realized we didn't want to use My Sites, so we turned those features off, and removed any of the profiles created under site/my/profiles.  This all worked fine except the reference to the picture (along with other fields like About me, Ask Me About, etc.) still remain.  How can I remove these, most importantly the Picture reference?  If I click Edit, the only option is to add an attachment.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any other way, than creating a script that will remove the picture information from User Profile..

Following code will help:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));
// accountName is Active Directory account
UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);
// PictureUrl is the property you need to set.. set it to Empty string..
userProfile["PictureUrl"].Value = string.Empty;
// commit the change
userProfile.Commit();
```

Well you can use Client Object Model and write the code as a Console/Windows application.. In that case you will be getting the reference of SPSite accordingly.. You can also port it as a Powershell script..

Reference:

[Update User Profile picture programmatically in SharePoint](http://sharepoint-tamizha.blogspot.com/2013/08/update-user-profile-picture.html)